# Key Derivation - CKDprv & CKDpub

Tags: private-key, public-key, child-chain

I would like to replicate this derivation of keys.

```
Chain m
ext pub: xpub661MyMwAqRbcFtXgS5sYJABqqG9YLmC4Q1Rdap9gSE8NqtwybGhePY2gZ29ESFjqJoCu1Rupje8YtGqsefD265TMg7usUDFdp6W1EGMcet8
ext prv: xprv9s21ZrQH143K3QTDL4LXw2F7HEK3wJUD2nW2nRk4stbPy6cq3jPPqjiChkVvvNKmPGJxWUtg6LnF5kejMRNNU3TGtRBeJgk33yuGBxrMPHi

Chain m/0H              
ext pub: xpub68Gmy5EdvgibQVfPdqkBBCHxA5htiqg55crXYuXoQRKfDBFA1WEjWgP6LHhwBZeNK1VTsfTFUHCdrfp1bgwQ9xv5ski8PX9rL2dZXvgGDnw
ext prv: xprv9uHRZZhk6KAJC1avXpDAp4MDc3sQKNxDiPvvkX8Br5ngLNv1TxvUxt4cV1rGL5hj6KCesnDYUhd7oWgT11eZG7XnxHrnYeSvkzY7d2bhkJ7

Chain m/0H/1           
ext pub: xpub6ASuArnXKPbfEwhqN6e3mwBcDTgzisQN1wXN9BJcM47sSikHjJf3UFHKkNAWbWMiGj7Wf5uMash7SyYq527Hqck2AxYysAA7xmALppuCkwQ
ext prv: xprv9wTYmMFdV23N2TdNG573QoEsfRrWKQgWeibmLntzniatZvR9BmLnvSxqu53Kw1UmYPxLgboyZQaXwTCg8MSY3H2EU4pWcQDnRnrVA1xe8fs
```

I correctly derived the keys in 0h using the CKDprv function. Here are the steps:

```
xpriv in m:

0488ade4 xpriv
00 depth
00000000 parent fingerprint 
00000000 key index
873dff81c02f525623fd1fe5167eac3a55a049de3d314bb42ee227ffed37d508  Chain Code
00e8f32e723decf4051aefac8e2c93c9c5b214313817cdb01a1494b917c8436b35  Key
e77e9d71 Checksum

CKDprv:
HMAC-SHA512 (873dff81c02f525623fd1fe5167eac3a55a049de3d314bb42ee227ffed37d508 (Parent's chain code); 00e8f32e723decf4051aefac8e2c93c9c5b214313817cdb01a1494b917c8436b3580000000 (Parent's Key + Child'index))

Result (64 bytes + 64 bytes):
04bfb2dd60fa8921c2a4085ec15507a921f49cdc839f27f0f280e9c1495d44b5
47fdacbd0f1097043b78c63c20c34ef4ed9a111d980047ad16282c7ae6236141  (Child's Chain Code)

To find the child's key, I added the first 64 bytes with the parent's key
```

Now, for the next step, having a non-hardened index, I wanted to use CKDpub.

```
This is the parent's public key:

0488b21e 
01 
3442193e 
80000000 
47fdacbd0f1097043b78c63c20c34ef4ed9a111d980047ad16282c7ae6236141 (Chain code)
035a784662a4a20a65bf6aab9ae98a6c068a81c52e4b032c0fb5400c706cfccc56 (Key)
b8b9c580


In the HMAC-SHA512 operation I pass these parameters as input:
47fdacbd0f1097043b78c63c20c34ef4ed9a111d980047ad16282c7ae6236141
035a784662a4a20a65bf6aab9ae98a6c068a81c52e4b032c0fb5400c706cfccc5600000001
```

I get this result (64 bytes + 64 bytes):

```
b7d40c610c146701cdabb2df826716086d591664eb77de90b40c115bb653fb4d 
5c8c3990242778e21f3d47c20428181c65de054baba9a156b798c0e85a10d9e4
```

By checking the chain code that the next key must have, the chain code obtained is wrong.

```
0488b21e
02
5c1bd648
00000001
**2a7857631386ba23dacac34180dd1983734e444fdbf774041578e9b6adb37c19**
03501e454bf00751f24b1b489aa925215d66af2234e3891c3b21a52bedb3cd711c
6f6e2af7
```

> What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you consistently getting the same result? Do you have any code showing what you are doing? I've just tried it myself using the inputs that you specified and got the expected result.

Comment: I used other HMAC calculator and got the correct result. I was probably wrong in entering the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to take m/0h public extended key:

`xpub68Gmy5EdvgibQVfPdqkBBCHxA5htiqg55crXYuXoQRKfDBFA1WEjWgP6LHhwBZeNK1VTsfTFUHCdrfp1bgwQ9xv5ski8PX9rL2dZXvgGDnw`

and derive m/0h/1 public extended key?

These are my values:

```
version: 0488b21e
depth: 02
fingerprint: 5c1bd648
child: 00000001
data: 03501e454bf00751f24b1b489aa925215d66af2234e3891c3b21a52bedb3cd711c
chain: 2a7857631386ba23dacac34180dd1983734e444fdbf774041578e9b6adb37c19
```

What is `b8b9c580` in your result? //edit: I am guessing it's the checksum.

```
chain input to HMAC: 47fdacbd0f1097043b78c63c20c34ef4ed9a111d980047ad16282c7ae6236141
data input to HMAC: 035a784662a4a20a65bf6aab9ae98a6c068a81c52e4b032c0fb5400c706cfccc5600000001
Calculated hmac: 4eb9d78157bae7a24115001621c4d91e3a3110e11e143c5259eaa4e55c5ec4bf2a7857631386ba23dacac34180dd1983734e444fdbf774041578e9b6adb37c19
left: 4eb9d78157bae7a24115001621c4d91e3a3110e11e143c5259eaa4e55c5ec4bf
right: 2a7857631386ba23dacac34180dd1983734e444fdbf774041578e9b6adb37c19
```

Looking at your values, they are correct except the HMAC result. In python you'd do:

```
I = hmac.new(chain, data, hashlib.sha512).digest()
```

I used bip32utils python library to present the result, the end result (m/0h/1 xpub) is correct.

Comment: @AndreaMelk is it a solution to your question?